# A question in alternative proof of Euler Criterion from David Burton's book

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am self studying Elementary number theory from David button an I am unable to understand the proof of Euler Criteria of quadratic residue ie when a constant a is solution of equation $ x^2$ $\equiv$ a (mod p) .

[image]

I have question only in Page 173 2 nd paragraph ie in the case when a is quadratic residue of p.

> I am unable to understand this proof from the line, to these (p-3) /2 congruences , add the congruence.

Can someone please explain the proof after the above mentioned line!! I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be good to consider an example.

Let $p=11$ and $a=3$. This is a quadratic residue, since $3^2\equiv5\pmod{11}$.
So take $x_1=5$. The first congruence is
$$x_1(p-x_1)=5\times 6\equiv-3\pmod{11}.$$
The remaining non-zero
residues modulo $11$ are $1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10$. We can pair these
off in congruences of the form $cc'\equiv3\pmod{11}$ as follows:
$$1\times 3\equiv3\pmod{11},$$
$$2\times 7\equiv3\pmod{11},$$
$$4\times 9\equiv3\pmod{11},$$
$$8\times 10\equiv3\pmod{11}.$$
Multiplying these five congruences together gives
$$10!\equiv-(3^5)\pmod{11}.$$
By Wilson,
$$-1\equiv-(3^5)\pmod{11}$$
and so
$$3^5\equiv1\pmod{11}.$$